# Remove Thunderbird and its files completely from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, thunderbird

I want to remove Thunderbird from my Ubuntu 18.04 so I have tried `sudo apt-get purge thunderbird*` and `sudo apt-get remove thunderbird` and also `sudo updatedb`  after them but `locate thunderbird` show 
(**note** I have delete some lines because this forum require that!)

```
abdelhakim@FILDSM:~$ locate thunderbird
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-thunderbird-next-bionic.list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mozillateam_ubuntu_thunderbird-next.gpg
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/ShutdownDuration.json

/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/1C885CF3CD4970FF7C33F7097E8F507172465C82
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/1D851CCC53B59E44AC72559ABA9C47D11ED47B78
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/1DA64A76CF503F4BAEC9D0C8795F647FB5C0D43E
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/1E08A054C3DEEAE5A9D8EE677AAC493071720796
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/1EA1FD53E4054408CFBA25F6DCCB208D6AEC0082
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/1EEB89797920315F59CD6A9A4D49A8A986D56155
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/1EED7F70592BA94C90FCFE0EAC1CDA67B579CB98
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/1FA4514C5310F68886300E9E43F4F115095325FE
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/2174E928BE75E22C9E499646A38DE10F8DB02F5B
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/24D5B6AD15F61FB613E9517289FF8D3E1CFBE3A0
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/24FDF5530BD5BE68A21DF1C62F304F8AB31E3448

/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/31792E3363AC421532C5F693080D8DB4913F6CE6
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/31C8A6955C7E7FAB4021C899E32AC3BB72F31493
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/32F86EF64D405D61F1C9935CFB401730D5B2FD8D
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/34F8511F3C0A2AC9C1194D46D9F4F745BB5D7BB6
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/35A8724F11EFCC4D5509B2FFF8B0F7721C147349
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/3600FBB01E3EF74FF1F623B7DF7657F1244DE54A
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/372F1EA24EED08EB6838EA846F1537ACA244C257
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/3768C3A9AD0FB3D2F2A0284219EEA186CEBA0119

/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/A35A7189D79E487BF77FD4001F8A575D7A2DE8E4
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/A3E7DFA2A9681F0F33D2F92024540F0A01CD1338
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/A4692C449318C79A6155A59A67B5390D0A62E641
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/A4D37D2DE3014DA8D384B28A5929F9D1BE60945D
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/A4FF63422A371C84216442FBFB80099B2567C93D
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/A504F7F89EB1C77B21AFC85F8F71191901119D2E
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/A52E09BB7B6ABD430827CB066D81377BD81DDCFE
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/A666B215CCC4EA91CED9D05BE8784C956804C038
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/A6A1399722893D123959220D3767377453B5C4E9
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/A7853EDD216D90511DB7E8DCAEDF8BC005E59FCB
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/A82766CB1FF1C45F79154889DDADB57911CCC86D
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/A84652CDE4E63E0ACA1DB42D2039539634722592
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/BB1ECC49BAD8AAC04D7918A74BC13987018BAB38
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/BB95D0607349D05725D5FE01D4FB300E319072AD
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/BD1637FF6A7687B372304CEB5B550F8F1B3D0890
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/BDCA22007597A65DCBE07D2C780AD8ADB433BD70
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/BDD154B3DCC201933E42E85629057C1CA63E1201
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/BDF55548BD631B884C99D511B6449114DC591F6D
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/BE918E09952B8773C6838FD152E71F2A4076EB24
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/BEE09A1726F4D2E33E31B0B4FC6BC029F41DA183
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/BF8F28384ADF3F0DF8EC2789C7D559CEC9457FE8
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/BFB5D7E631BE2A4EA925F1FF36C0F881FF59CC2E
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/BFDF6624A19063E7AECC4FF69BB02774F42A4CFA
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C021CEB166632B855777BDC55803FBC1177F6895
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C12070AD7F4102436A2CA6B80181AA5BD150E376
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C25E621290526A26779EBD0CE8BC33A69E3572C4
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C2725483E7DB51332C97725B0213BDF526F90E6F
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C2C980D13938C64357F22545556EEF32C24271FE
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C2F114DC51D0BA1FB8F530CD7B24D28DB184A1BB
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C47780A71CEA712A2580094D3934371D407EF287
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C478D910CCDD505A9D0DBCF7CBFEA67CB1807534
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C4A67357601BD3B81C693C3130472E59AAD0E818
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C4E173DD48B5766A20B5BDC4C9D6550321A6C254
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C5012778A19B98E09E1337A36EE90EBA247D2218
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C549FD25FE07A62E0132DEB8E569E4265684BC55
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C55F193E251433798DB7B69D0F47B3760C1BFCCF
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C574D56847776125224ABAACD924461B5DC8620F
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C5EA2CE7A1A4F68A4612CE8D9DFBD234D9255CE0
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C6C233845AC12DF3052A28C827771B47DBF2E7DC
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C822283FAA1C8864F7FA806C0E275EAB183444A9
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C86F5FB24DC9145E603C992A55752D6628C710A8
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C87E7D2571789AB97A3E1A81E16E0A539A4A7EE6
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/C972AC86BA22ADBFC038B134C02101C894D0078A
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/CA173C43178C1802FA3623CBD829F884C990D62A
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/CA191A2FCEC662C176F6C95C14C0691773AC872A
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/CB58BB8A2682329B1DA9715E63A68FDC4CAA4713
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/CBB8F022E3EAD3D9B115C43D28CCBE86D40B3C11
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/CC27CAA4DEAFA4862AAF96CDC11496ECCB57A37D
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/CD451E60359DD6C7735CF58E14ADAFC328738F4E
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/CD6D7A0CDA38E7EB126D4CE7E94D5DE3607E420E
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/CDF4A5E901BEDE7E4D0607FC10358F70010954B0
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/CEEB1B9AEAA5D09E171653452EABBFEA119E94BA
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/CFE13C06005E982AB139421FAC329C02CA67DDAA
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/D0865A1F03E3D2EEAE02F21C9DABB22CCD00DBD4
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/D08C37EBC0BB4D723BC58FE567D066B3C59BE65C
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/D24F7F81C7FA1BE6CD1C8FD7FAC2C3F91F3773A6
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/D378DD8576632C725F2D5B9F4698C6A355DBFC82
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/D4DC49A86F454BC9A98BE698DF8A25960B212D21
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/D6A32F90E953E2ECEE8E80789173AFC7F40EB779
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/D7960F1B0D83636C7BF043C45DF0D284BE635CAD
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/D7A5297F0385ED65918048DE73B036B8294C848D
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/D7AF5B18FFBD2A8F7C871CF651383CE234F4BE9E
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/D7EE0F250B47A85493B91DE71D918FDED4FF6640
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/D8257E98F8A181BD2B86260CA73B303E2555828A
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/D8A92C7B0366D5E94D3DAE52FF718F159B0238EF
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/D8AF5B03E238F7737357E142945B17312E775EC8
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/D8CFDE6EFFC7DFF205FA7905F7898C003742A10E
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/D9AEE38DE447E8ABF03DC2201659F6CF972AEAEA
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/DA329702F3386C0E8AC06C0A0B80684FC0437112
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/DA8544B052E22442E032492B6A3ED489601C761F
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/DA8684C00C4D399D4F95E842E9B4D656CD79C46B
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/DACE69D0755441802AE5766F9506BD0CC8625B37
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/DC46F772E04807F4068896AD19427889E59C7760
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/DD6BDA70ADEC073A8F06048FD694D0366918BE17
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/DD9E2262DB64F2BA4DA876CFDA8566BD6E8040AB
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/DDC8963DEB620343398FCCEC27A0BA4C11B3C611
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/DE046058D07B0E48092B6D7CE5F9F4FD54232589
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/DE17A62DBDF4C051952841D7698140431DB8BCE8
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/DE3367A9B56B61D2DB59B241D29EB58BF2856FC8
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E0361506C6220831AA3810D4E1D416BE6EE7420C
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E043D5408B65FFBA738975974B0CE3ACADBEC800
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E0490B4F5E209D6455BB2124CB805A3D0AC088FA
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E04E8FDC6DD65EE67C81DF6FC5D7C648C2F66B7E
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E051959FF891FB0155AFA31FA340DDD231AA5ED3
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E07619B5BDAC24BF8717437E05B3D641F34009B4
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E244475F8E853DC8D071CE23BB3C5209151F23BA
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E2B83AFEFC397688131BC4F77EA249ED9D1B910D
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E2EE6F8B8B28AD1A762595D71C9F0472441211E9
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E32709000772704E6208D6A3A801EE4E0A335BC9
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E34C9660512C5C1092C528EEE541D5D98639AEBD
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E3D258E2C0D727136E26AA8E1C7A316C2EA50915
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E41FA711C5386C352DC978C9389BFDFCAA16A0D1
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E449E002F3F8F4B20440A3808607F97914847596
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E4AD83379683B9F6A083BF29FC496DF632878944
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E4C618457DF48B67689105661EF967CC0A08310B
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E50937267CC7612B5B17C8A1CE44058A6500F244
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E556A9BF4C11B488520347673F1CA8CD532CE8C2
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E590F0E4F54830AE2D323E4321353F872EC157B1
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E6B1BD3EEC8943F6FC116AA6DA8735760DAD9AE4
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E89D3226AEBADD2AB3BC16C6CA3B986F2A2EAC05
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/E952A4A4D10774CD52CE6388D816F8D3EB947B2E
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/EB87EDAFFA12CBA717EDE6E9FBB1B14F8011EFE5
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/EC85E7990B1BA3ACFAEB81435F492CF9191C0323
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/ED79D909A2A11EF2A8D7E32BCCDD49E6C7701EB8
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/EDCBFB4FE567347EDCFAEB4580A3F1E83B4B3AA4
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/EF08FA888C9D14B95CB27ADE985048BCFBB2B730
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/EFB1EEBA52913E01C287FBD9E31629306E785C80
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/EFC88B2AF38EDDE280FDD461B85182C55A8C96FC
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F00CEC8C2515185AA1777B6595F20C317BBCD842
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F035CFE3DABFD07A3A4E99A79E528EC3E2FD5DF0
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F04325AB85D865806CE83FB963CE155A5D381194
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F0B959543CF43A22D0D73E707D3AC952C946905B
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F1201A04AE95B1CDDC876B043753E80CFDA69539
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F1D396132F82F9147FD674A2F7CB9CA941A4E7CB
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F248F91684C31413CCE55C4895E21C9E1D8041B4
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F27CB20624C839CF4FCE3DABEFBF4840C2447C8A
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F3410B10172274B082DD7324595E1414424FB5C8
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F3BA5064CDBA8DCAB36B1B3490371794D74C252E
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F3DD3BE22E764808AF013CA7957A733D53070419
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F41F4D9E4A8AAFD861312674D16BD3221B6F9D9A
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F64E14C75ED2567EEED0A17BD6CB6E92B26C6FAA
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F729D5241C4173CF8761B5000264B7A42589BE9B
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F74C08DF1D9EC8E6840604FDAE57DD120BAA7E82
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F826CD8F3E6AA7695EEA38D24CD9F59A6223D46A
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F85F070A52CB182AE4D2AAC4DD13058A2947168C
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F8A136F929B620A45716BEBC69B407DF869E7B79
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F8B19AC7986A8EBD3CCD87CB02AA8C23EF85415F
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F8C285C8BBFA44E39F283F76C73B3BB390B8687E
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/F935AF8871EE9204F0D5E45347B52B66C1332D3E
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/FA0A33529B850874418E98C216AC0351FACCD034
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/FA53E61BC808E8DE50D4A3FB9678DEF6DC50D1A9
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/FB21A57F9EE5B68D1A5564F41723A82D916AA16F
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/FB4F64DC69CFE841A537FD3DD5392480B3156E96
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/FCFEA56DC97EDC7BC2CD55D2589D361DD9EE4133
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/FD3C3005C98412FC6C682DCDA5E2BE5B107A76FF
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/FD50AEDA91C249EC9E0F2FBD536B40AE4137A31F
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/FE061D178CECDA9A6CDAEE7636E6CD785BCFE5E2
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/FE0E89F78529540C0ACEE578263EA29CFE5B81C7
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/FF2464016EEA96D817E868CAF695C098A7DEB922
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/FF2D317A3C1556D3082B9CF70FC692F5A773BE7C
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/FF6A88F17BBFB4BB7832611D21612032FAB1A95D
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/FF719050703F3BE3AE8A75CA3D1C18F8E360F2E6
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/FFAB239C4773290BCA23910871DF95F3C7109B79
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cache2/entries/FFCCCD5E2993F05F18846893A65D9B4DD6731AFC
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird/21an2w88.default/startupCache/startupCache.8.little
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/Crash Reports
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/profiles.ini
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/.parentlock
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/AlternateServices.txt
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/ImapMail
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/Mail
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/SecurityPreloadState.txt
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/SiteSecurityServiceState.txt
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/abook.mab
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/addonStartup.json.lz4
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/addons.json
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/blist.sqlite
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/blocklist-addons.json
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/blocklist-gfx.json
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/blocklist-plugins.json
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/blocklist.xml
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cert8.db
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cert_override.txt
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/compatibility.ini
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/content-prefs.sqlite
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/cookies.sqlite
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/crashes
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/datareporting
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/directoryTree.json
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/downloads.json
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/extensions.json
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/favicons.sqlite
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/folderTree.json
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/formhistory.sqlite
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/global-messages-db.sqlite
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/gmp
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/history.mab
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/key3.db
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/kinto.sqlite
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/localstore.rdf
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/logins.json
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/mailViews.dat
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/minidumps
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/panacea.dat
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/permissions.sqlite
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/places.sqlite
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/pluginreg.dat
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/prefs.js
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/revocations.txt
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/saved-telemetry-pings
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/search.json.mozlz4
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/secmod.db
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/session.json
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/sessionCheckpoints.json
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/storage.sqlite
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/times.json
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/virtualFolders.dat
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/webappsstore.sqlite
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/xulstore.json
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/ImapMail/imap-mail.outlook.com.msf
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/ImapMail/imap.gmail-1.com
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/ImapMail/imap.gmail-1.com.msf
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/ImapMail/imap.gmail-2.com
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/ImapMail/imap.gmail-2.com.msf
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/ImapMail/imap.gmail.com
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/ImapMail/imap.gmail.com.msf
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/ImapMail/mail.etu.usthb.dz.msf
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/ImapMail/mail.univ-ghardaia.dz.msf
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/ImapMail/imap.gmail-1.com/INBOX.msf
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/ImapMail/imap.gmail-2.com/INBOX.msf
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/ImapMail/imap.gmail.com/INBOX.msf
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/Mail/Local Folders
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/Mail/Local Folders/Trash
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/Mail/Local Folders/Trash.msf
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/Mail/Local Folders/Unsent Messages
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/Mail/Local Folders/Unsent Messages.msf
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/crashes/events
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/crashes/store.json.mozlz4
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/crashes/events/30e0d057-ec7a-065a-415db637-13ec68ee
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/datareporting/session-state.json
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/datareporting/state.json
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/gmp/Linux_x86_64-gcc3
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/minidumps/35d37805-660d-2ca1-5defdb10-0fd1571d.dmp
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/minidumps/35d37805-660d-2ca1-5defdb10-0fd1571d.extra
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/saved-telemetry-pings/1183c328-ec19-41d7-bb7a-5aed60a710a3
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/saved-telemetry-pings/72f01e46-45ce-4e3c-8dd7-2e4dbe031b92
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/saved-telemetry-pings/e1a745b7-ebe8-4bfd-a621-acab4c745b2a
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/21an2w88.default/saved-telemetry-pings/e438415b-c621-4158-94c3-9d293269f194
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/Crash Reports/InstallTime20180710084133
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/Crash Reports/LastCrash
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/Crash Reports/crashreporter.ini
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/Crash Reports/events
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/Crash Reports/pending
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/Crash Reports/submit.log
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/Crash Reports/submitted
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird/Crash Reports/submitted/bp-a0feb22b-8d5a-4d3a-b8a5-43d6c0180804.txt
/snap/gtk-common-themes/319/share/icons/HighContrast/scalable/apps-extra/thunderbird-icon.svg
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/scalable/apps-extra/thunderbird-icon.svg
/var/cache/apt/archives/thunderbird-gnome-support_1%3a52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/thunderbird-locale-de_1%3a52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/thunderbird-locale-en-us_1%3a52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/thunderbird-locale-en_1%3a52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/thunderbird-locale-es_1%3a52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/thunderbird-locale-fr_1%3a52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/thunderbird-locale-it_1%3a52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/thunderbird-locale-pt_1%3a52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/thunderbird-locale-ru_1%3a52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/thunderbird-locale-zh-hans_1%3a52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/thunderbird-locale-zh-hant_1%3a52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/thunderbird_1%3a52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/thunderbird_1%3a57.0~b2+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
/var/crash/_usr_lib_thunderbird_thunderbird.1000.crash
/var/crash/_usr_lib_thunderbird_thunderbird.1000.upload
/var/crash/_usr_lib_thunderbird_thunderbird.1000.uploaded
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_mozillateam_thunderbird-next_ubuntu_dists_bionic_InRelease
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_mozillateam_thunderbird-next_ubuntu_dists_bionic_main_binary-amd64_Packages
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_mozillateam_thunderbird-next_ubuntu_dists_bionic_main_binary-i386_Packages
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_mozillateam_thunderbird-next_ubuntu_dists_bionic_main_i18n_Translation-en
/var/lib/flatpak/app/com.skype.Client/x86_64/stable/9ef340360c6d81f2602f6672765e701d4641c428171d060765610549bb033352/files/share/icons/HighContrast/scalable/apps-extra/thunderbird-icon.svg
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.28/cc7c2dd516160674998803e6ed6838091d628a3d25ff7465485ddecfb9f4363f/files/share/icons/HighContrast/scalable/apps-extra/thunderbird-icon.svg
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/
```

is not part of the thunderbird package but is what you downloaded. You need to remove those manually.

```
/var/lib/apt/lists/
```

is also not part of the thunderbird package but is the PPA you still have. Also needs manual removing.

```
/home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird
/home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird
```

are part of the personal settings for thunderbird. If those are related to the package you installed and not a manual install those should have been removed when you "purged" it. You can remove these manually too...

```
rm -rf /home/abdelhakim/.thunderbird
rm -rf /home/abdelhakim/.cache/thunderbird
```

and then `sudo updatedb` again.

For the others: I do not believe crash reports are deleted when you delete software so that is another manual delete you could do.

Comment: thank you, i didnt find any official way to fully uninstall / reset thundebird

Answer (score 2):

Thunderbird is default mail client for Ubuntu 18.04.

**You can uninstall it from Synaptic Package Manager**

- Click Administration under the System menu, then click Synaptic
  Package Manager.
- In the Quick search box, type "Thunderbird" and then press Enter on
  your keyboard.
- A list of software that you can install (called packages) appears.
  Find Thunderbird in the list, right-click on it, and then click on
  Mark for complete removal from the menu that appears.
- Click the Apply button.
- After Thunderbird is uninstalled, start Nautilus and press Ctrl+H to
  show hidden files. Then, delete the folder .thunderbird in
  your home directory and ~/.cache/thunderbird.

For Windows and Mac uninstallation see;
http://write.flossmanuals.net/thunderbird/removing-thunderbird/.